# Scss styling not applied to Vue component

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an `Img` component that consists of a figure with a nested image:

```html
<figure>
  <img @dragstart="stopDrag" :src="src" />
</figure>
```

This component is used in another component, where I'm trying to overwrite the inner figure/image's style from the parent. The figure does get new styling, but the inner image does not.

```html
<template>
    <List>
      <li class="gridItem">
        <Img :src="require('@/assets/images/girl.png')" />
      </li>
    </List>
<template>

...

<style scoped lang="scss">
.gridItem {
  & figure {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    //I did try & >>> img, and it didn't work.

    & img {
      width: auto;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

The current version of this project is on my Github, so maybe it's easier to see the problem with a cloned repo? [Github Repo](https://github.com/HenrikDK2/VueProjekt)

Comment: Use the `>>>` (deep) selector to ensure that `figure[data-v-id] img` is correctly created from the scoped styling.

Comment: I did try using the deep nested selector, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>>>` seem to have no effect for the Sass implementations I've tried, including `node-sass` and `sass`. On the other hand, `node-sass` and `sass` still support `/deep/`.

The following SCSS works for scoped styles with [`node-sass` 4.14.1](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-curran-jy5jx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark) and [`sass` 1.26.9](https://codesandbox.io/s/deep-selector-in-vue-using-dart-sass-xevdb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark):

```css
.gridItem {
  & figure {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    & /deep/ img {
      width: 500px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We just made the post at the same time :D, but it's the correct solution. But ::v-deep works for my project.

Comment: Oh interesting. I tried `::v-deep` unsuccessfully in Codesandbox.

Comment: I have no idea, sometimes frameworks have their own way of creating problems. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

According to Vue own [documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles)

*"Some pre-processors, such as Sass, may not be able to parse >>> properly. In those cases you can use the /deep/ or ::v-deep combinator instead - both are aliases for >>> and work exactly the same."*

So instead of `& >>> img` do `&::v-deep img`. I hope this fixes your issue.